# Add layouts from resources dynamically

Tags: android, layout, dynamic

I have one dynamic array that I'm getting it from REST.

If it has 3 arrays inside, I need to put 3 layouts in my view in order to the user can select one of them. Is like inflate a ListView, but creating textview and button in each of them.

How can I make this?
[image: Example]
thanks

Comment: As I understand, you need to make xml layout and inflate it in runtime dynamically as much as you need.

Comment: not clear about what is your exact requirement

Comment: sorry @DavidJhons, I need to do something to make this

![Example](https://xceed.me/example.jpg)